# What is "KK1 enzyme"?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, human-physiology

In the book "The Kaizen Way" by Robert Maurer, I've read the following:

> When we’re sitting, our muscles go into a form of hibernation, causing
> our bodies to shut down the enzyme (called KK1) that breaks down some
> of the fat in the blood.

However, when I tried to google "KK1 enzyme", I got nothing about any enzyme. I mean, I got [this website](https://www.juststand.org/the-facts/) and [this article](https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2010/06/with-fasting-enzyme-turns-off-bodys-production-of-fats-cholesterol/), but they don't contain the name "KK1" at all.

What was meant by that? Is it scientifically accurate?

Comment: KK1 is a [putative potassium channel blocker](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q8MXD2) in the venom of the Manchurian scorpion, but I couldn't find any evidence for a mammalian KK1 protein of any function, let alone fat metabolism.

Comment: Sounds as if he has no idea what he is talking about. I'd trash the book immediately.